# openCV text on image - background image does not clear

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking to print text on images and create a video out of it, in order to visually see some data (and how it is changing).

I wanted to load the background image ONCE and then each frame make the "frame_img" equal to the background image and then print the values on the frame:

```
bg_img = cv2.imread('background_image.jpg')
for frame_num in range(n_frames):
  print(f'Frame: {frame_num}')
  frame_img = bg_img #reset frame to background
  for gxi in range(gxn):
    for gyi in range(gyn):
      txt = str(int(np_vec[frame_num,gyi,gxi,feature_index]))
      loc = (int((gxi+0.4)*gxd),int((gyi+0.7)*gyd))
      cv2.putText(frame_img, txt, loc, font, fontScale, font_color, text_thickness, cv2.LINE_AA);
  vidout.write(frame_img.astype(np.uint8))
vidout.release()
```

The issue I am having is that the outcome frames have the text written on top of each other as if the frame_img is not being reset to the background

The following works, but I do not want to read the background image every time:

```
for frame_num in range(n_frames):
  print(f'Frame: {frame_num}')
  frame_img = cv2.imread('background_image.jpg') #reset frame to background
  for gxi in range(gxn):
    for gyi in range(gyn):
      txt = str(int(np_vec[frame_num,gyi,gxi,feature_index]))
      loc = (int((gxi+0.4)*gxd),int((gyi+0.7)*gyd))
      cv2.putText(frame_img, txt, loc, font, fontScale, font_color, text_thickness, cv2.LINE_AA);
  vidout.write(frame_img.astype(np.uint8))
vidout.release()
```

Any idea why the background image (frame_img) is not being reset?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
frame_img = bg_img
```

You are assigning reference to the object instead of value. The solution would be to assign the copy of original image like so

```
frame_img = bg_img.copy()
```